# Start path when using Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to specify an "start path" when using `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` ?

When I use it like this:

```
 Intent chooseFolderIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(chooseFolderIntent, getString(R.string.save_to_directory)), CHOOSE_FOLDER_CODE);
```

It starts displaying all the folders from the root of the phone. But I would like it to start displaying a certain path (eg. DCIM folder)

Is there any extras I can use to specify this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On API 26+, you can use [DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract.html#EXTRA_INITIAL_URI) to set the initial directory for the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` Intent. Note that the URI must be one retrieved from the Storage Access Framework APIs (i.e., it must be a document tree URI).

There's no way to do this pre-API 26.

Comment: But how do you get the first URI? My customers have extreme trouble locating where they want to grant access, as most all devices require going "menu->Show SD card" or "Menu->Show Internal Storage" the first time the doc picker launches.

Comment: If I first time to start this `Intent`, how do I have the "previous" `uri`?

Comment: @Justin did you find how to provide Uri on the first time?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (tested on two Android 11 phones):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    String folder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    if (!folder.isEmpty()) {
         Uri initialFolderUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(folder + "/Pictures/"));
         if (initialFolderUri != null)
             intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, initialFolderUri);
    }
}
```

I don't know if all this error checking is required, I added it to be on the safe side.